# Laravel - Query nested relationship with Laravel when clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

```
// This comes in as an array - item_category[]
$category = \Request::input('item_category'); 

Item::with('category')
    ->when($category, function($q) use ($category) {
        $q->whereHas('category', function($q) use ($category) {
            $q->whereIn('category', $category);
        });
    })->get();
```

Hello, I am trying to retrieve all items where the category equals the any of the categories that is passed through. However, the category is a filter and the user may or may not check this, hence the when clause chained to the model. The code currently throws an error

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `items` where `has` = category)
```

If i do

```
    Item::with('category')
    ->whereHas('category', function($q) use ($category) {
            $q->whereIn('category', $category);
        })->get();
```

This will work, except if the user doesn't check any of the item_category checkboxes, the query will return 0 results since it is expecting this value to pass through. 
I really don't know what do here. Any advice. 
Regards,

items table

```
 id   category_id   title   description   price   timestamps
```

categories table

```
 id   category
```

Item.php

```
 public function category()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
 }
```

Comment: Please show us the original tables and the final MySQL query you want.

Comment: Again, you should consider showing us the raw MySQL query you want.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Laravel is interpreting your nested `whereHas(...)` as `where('has', ...)` rather than as what you want. I don't know why, but I'm guessing that's how subclauses work.

What you could do is first create the base query, then make the check yourself and augment it, like this:

```
$category = \Request::input('item_category'); 
$query = Item::with('category');
if ($category)  {
    $query->whereHas('category', function($q) use ($category) {
        $q->whereIn('category', $category);
    });
}
$results = $query->get();
```

Although shouldn't that be category_id rather than category?

Comment: It's possible that the closure passed as the second parameter when calling `when()` receives an instance of the database query builder which doesn't support `whereHas` (unlike the Eloquent query builder), and thus the function call was interpreted as `where('has', ...)`.

Comment: Yes, that sounds likely. Thanks for the addition, @KemalFadillah